# Open an IO stream from a local file or url

Tags: ruby, stream

I know there are libs in other languages that can take a string that contains either a path to a local file or a url and open it as a readable IO stream.

Is there an easy way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

[open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) is part of the standard Ruby library, and it will redefine the behavior of `open` so that you can open a url, as well as a local file.  It returns a `File` object, so you should be able to call methods like `read` and `readlines`.

```
require 'open-uri'
file_contents = open('local-file.txt') { |f| f.read }
web_contents  = open('http://www.stackoverflow.com') {|f| f.read }
```

Comment: Is there a way to return a file object like you did here from an ActionMailer attachment?

Comment: Know this is a bit old now, but you can also do: `content = open("http://example.com").read`

Comment: You can, but doing it outside the closure like that will keep the file descriptor open. This may be a problem for some usages.

Comment: note that `open-uri` will not **stream** a file, so you can't read a first 4k of it. `open-uri` will read a **whole** file to memory at moment of opening.

Comment: `URI.parse('http://www.stackoverflow.com').open { |f| f.read }` If you looking for a way to insure it does not call `Kernal.open`. Also gets around rubocop security rules.

Comment: `open-uri` isn't needed with Ruby 2.7.1. I don't know for the other versions.

Comment: Your first `open` call now throws: "(irb):2:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://www.stackoverflow.com (Errno::ENOENT)"