# How do I open a web page and write it to a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I run a simple script using [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html), I can access a web page. The results get written to the terminal.

Normally I would use bash redirection to write the results to a file.

How do I use ruby to write the results of an OpenURI call to a file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'

open("file_to_write.html", "wb") do |file|
  URI.open("http://www.example.com/") do |uri|
     file.write(uri.read)
  end
end
```

Note: In Ruby < 2.5 you must use `open(url)` instead of `URI.open(url)`. See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15893

Comment: Worthing pointing out that there is no error checking. Problems can occur with both the URI and the local disk open calls. For simple scripts it might not be a problem. For anything that needs long term reliability you'll want to add some safety nets.

Comment: Where does this file get saved to?

Comment: In the file `file_to_write` in the current directory of the process. You can provide a full path instead.

Answer (score 0):

<s>[The pickaxe to the rescue.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_io.html)</s> (this used to be a good page, but is no longer working)

Try this instead: [Open an IO stream from a local file or url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263536/open-an-io-stream-from-a-local-file-or-url)