# Ruby read remote file to stream

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, iostream

I need to save a remote file a cloud storage server,so I must read this file to a file stream,I found this article :
[Open an IO stream from a local file or url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263536/open-an-io-stream-from-a-local-file-or-url)
the answer is :

```
require 'open-uri'
file_contents = open('local-file.txt') { |f| f.read }
web_contents  = open('http://www.stackoverflow.com') {|f| f.read }
```

But the `web_contents` is not right.Then I compare this action to a custom local file upload,which format is `ASCII-8BIT`,the format is not same.so How can I get the correct stream from remote file .

Answer (score 5):

Seems all right to me:

```
require 'open-uri'
web_contents  = open('http://www.stackoverflow.com') {|f| f.read }

out_file = File.expand_path("~/Desktop/out.html")

File.open(out_file, "w") do |f|
  f.puts web_contents
end
```

Comment: What about performance? Is that the best way to do that? eg: If my file is 500MB for example

Comment: If you don't want to load it up in memory, then you can read it in chunks (lines?).

Comment: sorry man, I didn't use it yet. Do you have some example? Or can improve your answer here with this? Thanks