# How to open a URL and count image tags in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get

I am trying to modify this code from the Bastards book of Ruby:

```
require "open-uri"
url = "http://www.nytimes.com"
pattern = "<img"   

page = open(url).read
tags = page.scan(pattern)
puts "The site #{url} has #{tags.length} img tags"
```

I want to modify it so the program asks for a URL and then counts the tags. I've only been programming a few days. Here is my code. It probably contains multiple errors:

```
require "open-uri"
puts "Enter URL"
urlnew = gets
urlnew = URI.encode(urlnew)
URI.parse(urlnew)
page = open(urlnew).read
pattern = "<img"   
tags = page.scan(pattern)
puts "The site #{url} has #{tags.length} img tags"
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Enter URL                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
www.google.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - www.google.com%0A (Errno::ENOENT)                                                                             
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'                                                                                                                                                  
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'                                                                                                                                                  
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/ruby/hello.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried various methods to get URL input.

[Open an IO stream from a local file or url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263536/open-an-io-stream-from-a-local-file-or-url)

None seem to work. Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chomp` to remove new line char present at the end of user input

```
urlnew = gets.chomp
```

Also, make sure you enter `http://` in the URL. Or you could add the below line to your code

```
urlnew = "http://#{urlnew}" unless urlnew.start_with?("http://")
```

Here is complete working program:

```
require "open-uri"
puts "Enter URL"
urlnew = gets.chomp
urlnew = "http://#{urlnew}" unless urlnew.start_with?("http://")
urlnew = URI.encode(urlnew)
URI.parse(urlnew)
page = open(urlnew).read
pattern = "<img"   
tags = page.scan(pattern)
puts "The site #{urlnew} has #{tags.length} img tags"
```

Sample run:

```
> ruby test.rb
Enter URL
stackoverflow.com
The site http://stackoverflow.com has 16 img tags
```

Comment: I tried chomp + an http:// prefix. I now get:                                                                                                            uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Comment: @RubyRube that error has nothing to do with `chomp` or the prefix.

Comment: I just corrected the error. I am now getting the following output: /home/ubuntu/workspace/ruby/hello.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `url' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: @RubyRube  You should be using `url_new` ...right?  Take a deep breath and look at your code - all hints are in the error message

Comment: @RubyRube Stack Overflow is not a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop), you are supposed to show some effort ;-)

Comment: Stefan, I spent an hour going through various configurations, but I admit I did not paste them. In future I will be clear as to what I have tried.

Comment: Wandmaker, that works, thanks for typing that up. I tried it without chomp and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @RubyRube I mean the subsequent errors (regarding `Rails` and `url`) - you should try to fix these yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In order to Parse the `HTML` response body , It is advisable to use `nokogiri library` [Nokogiri Ruby Library](http://www.nokogiri.org/) .

```
require 'nokogiri'
require "open-uri"
puts "Enter URL"
urlnew = URI.encode(gets.chop)
URI.parse(urlnew)
page = open(urlnew).read
html = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(page)
result = html.css('img').count
puts "The site #{result} has #{result.length} img tags"
```